# AngularJs error Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

This is module

```
(function(){

    /**
    * app Module
    *
    * Description
    */
    angular.module('app',[]);
})();
```

I have this service

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('homeservice',homeservice);

homeservice.$inject = ['$http']

function homeservice($http){

    var service = {
        test : test
    }
    return service;

    /**
     * get articles
     * @return {[type]} [description]
     */
    function test(){
      $http.get('/test')
         .then(testSuccess)
         .catch(testError)

      function testSuccess(response){
         return response.data;
         //console.log(response.data) this line prints data to console
      }

      function testError(error){
         return error;
      }
    }
}
})();
```

This is my controller which calls function

```
(function(){


angular.module('app')
       .controller('HomeController',HomeController);

    HomeController.$inject = ['homeservice']
    function HomeController(homeservice) {
        var vm = this;

        test();

        function test(){
             homeservice.test().then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
        }

    }
    })();
```

I keep getting the error - ***Cannot read property 'then' of undefined*** when I call a method in my controller. I have used this way before and It works properly.

**ANSWER**

```
function test(){
          return $http.get('/test') // return was missing here
             .then(testSuccess)
             .catch(testError)

          function testSuccess(response){
             return response.data;
             //console.log(response.data) this line prints data to console
          }

          function testError(error){
             return error;
          }
        }
```

I was missing **return** at **$http.get('/test')**

Comment: did you defined the module?

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes the module is defined , forgot to add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
homeservice.test().then(function(response){ ... });
```

presumes that `test` method should return a promise. And it returns `undefined`, that's what the error says.

It should be

```
/**
 * get articles
 * @return {[type]} [description]
 */
function test(){
  return $http.get('/test')
     .then(testSuccess)
     .catch(testError)

  ...
}
```

Comment: When I console.log response from factory , it outputs data to console. But controller throws error .

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The code in the question misses `return` statement, that's why you get `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error. If you're continuing to get the error after applying this answer, please, provide a plunk, so the problem could be replicated.

Answer (score 1):

The test function needs to **return** the `$http` promise:

```
function test(){
  ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟  $http.get('/test')
//^^^^^^ ---------------------RETURN the $http promise
     .then(testSuccess)
     .catch(testError)

  function testSuccess(response){
     return response.data;
  }

  function testError(error){
     ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶;̶
     //throw to chain rejection
     throw error;
  }
}
```

The `return` statements in the success and error handlers do not return values to the parent function. Put `return` statements at each level of the hierarchy.

---

## Rejection re-throw for older versions of AngularJS

Previously (versions <1.6), an error [thrown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) from a promise's `onFulfilled` or `onRejection` handlers would also be passed to the `$exceptionHandler()` (in addition to rejecting the promise with the error as reason).

To avoid an error message in the console with older versions, re-throw by returning a rejected promise:

```
  function onRejection(error){
     ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶;̶
     console.log(error.status);
     //throw to chain rejection
     return $q.reject(error);
  }
```

A common problem for novice programmers is rejected promises getting erroneously **converted** to fulfilled promises. It is important to **re-throw errors from a rejection handler.**

Also when a function omit a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return), that function returns a value of `undefined` which erroneously **converts** a rejection to a fulfilled promise that resolves to a value of `undefined`.

From the Docs:

> Due to [e13eea](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e13eeabd7e34a78becec06cfbe72c23f2dcb85f9), an error thrown from a promise's `onFulfilled` or `onRejection` handlers is treated exactly the same as a regular rejection. Previously, it would also be passed to the `$exceptionHandler()` (in addition to rejecting the promise with the error as reason).
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to v1.6 ($q)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$q)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
$http.get('/test')
  .success(successFunction)
  .error(errorFunction);
```

At least, that's for versions < 1.4.8

For versions > 1.4.8 try this:

```
$http.get('/test')
  .then(
    function(response) { }, // success
    function(response) { } // failure
  );
```

Comment: I am using AngularJs version 1.6.0 , but even if i try this it throws another error : **$http.get(...).success is not a function**

Comment: I changed it to include the syntax for > 1.4.8 see if that changes anything.

Comment: That does not fix my problem since my logic is the same .

Comment: No, it shouldn't. `success` was deprecated long before 1.4.8.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('homeservice',homeservice);

homeservice.$inject = ['$http']

function homeservice($http){
   return {
        test: function () {
            console.log("inside function");
            return $http.get('stats.json');
        }
    };
}
})();
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/IrTxihMdcl5BVshumsVE?p=preview)**